# Value of the argument label in Swift4

Tags: swift

In this reference manual for Swift4.
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html

and I have seen tutorial and iOS usage of parameter labels.

What is the value of using those parameter or argument labels?

```
func greet(person: String, from hometown: String) -> String {
    return "Hello \(person)!  Glad you could visit from \(hometown)."
}

print(greet(person: "Bill", from: "Cupertino"))
```

Above, what is the value of declaring "from" in the greet function?

```
func greet(person: String, hometown: String) -> String {
    return "Hello \(person)!  Glad you could visit from \(hometown)."
}

print(greet(person: "Bill", hometown: "Cupertino"))
```

Comment: Have you read the [Function Argument Labels and Parameter Names](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-ID166) section?

Comment: yes.  What specifically are you highlighting in that ?

Comment: It explains what the argument label and the parameter names are for. You need to clarify your question explaining what it is that you don't understand.

Comment: the value of the question shouldn't be voted down.  Actually, if the caller needs to specify a label but that label changes or there are two labels for the same parameter, that makes maintaining a shared library of code written in swift harder to maintain.

Comment: that I can understand is actually you asking about what is the need to use function that have some input parameter ? in response to your question What is the value of using those parameter or argument labels? is it so ?

Comment: Right.  I am asking about the second argument label, not why parameters are valuable for functions.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend reading the [Swift API Design Guidelines](https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/#parameter-names)

Ultimately it's just the opinion of the designers/community that this is how they want things to work. The general reasoning being that it promotes clarity and brevity at the point of use, and feels more like a sentence. "Greet Bill hometown Cupertino" vs "Greet person Bill from Cupertino"

Comment: I see -- it is more of a style guideline rather than a functional value.